Cassandra 3.11.10 sstable utilities are missing in /bin directory of my cassandra database
We have our Cassandra cluster running on 3.11.10 as you can see from the below
nodetool version
ReleaseVersion: 3.11.10
Cassandra is installed on Linux OS of version '7' as you can see from the below
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

By the time I joined my current organization , I see Cassandra was already installed on the machines and it was live for usage . When I checked, Some of the regularly useful sstable utilities like sstabledump or sstablemetadata are missing in the /bin directory where I can see only the below 4 sstable utilities exist.
/bin # ls -lrt | grep -i sstable
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root       2042 Jan 29  2021 sstableverify
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root       2045 Jan 29  2021 sstableutil
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root       2042 Jan 29  2021 sstableupgrade
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root       2042 Jan 29  2021 sstablescrub
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root       2034 Jan 29  2021 sstableloader

I tried installing the remaining using "yum install cassandra-tools" but , it is throwing the below error and the missing utilities are not getting installed .
yum install cassandra-tools
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
customer-configs                                                                                                   | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
openbet                                                                                                            | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
s3-centos-gluster8                                                                                                 | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
s3-datadog                                                                                                         | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
s3-mariadb                                                                                                         | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
s3-php74                                                                                                           | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
s3_base                                                                                                            | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
s3_centos-sclo-rh                                                                                                  | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
s3_centos-sclo-sclo                                                                                                | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
s3_centosplus                                                                                                      | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
s3_epel                                                                                                            | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
s3_extras                                                                                                          | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
s3_updates                                                                                                         | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
s3_varnish-52                                                                                                      | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
sgdigital-sportsbook                                                                                               | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
customer-configs/primary_db                                                                                        |  17 kB  00:00:00
No package cassandra-tools available.
Error: Nothing to do

Could you please help us with a way for us to get those utilities on to our Cassandra boxes.

The Cassandra tools you are referring to (sstabledump, sstablemetadata) are not located in the bin/ directory. They are installed in the tools/bin/ directory.
The cassandra-tools package is already installed which is why your attempt to install it failed. Cheers!
